# Regex to search specified log schema against invalid count of arguments

Tags: regex

At first I would like to note I am not familiar with advanced regex solutions. I used it for simple matching only. I have inherited a project from other developer - application with 15k of individual log entries.

I need a regex which will search for defined schema of log and will match any in which count of %X will not match count of arguments

Example of valid log is:

```
g_Log.Add(0, __FILE__, __FUNCTION__, "[LuckyItem][Strengten Item] Strenghten Fail [%s][%s] Name[%s] Type[%d] Serial[%I64d] Invalid ItemType[%d]",
        lpObj->AccountID, lpObj->Name, pTarget->GetName(), pTarget->m_Type,
        pTarget->m_Number, iItemType);
```

As you can see in the log message contained in " ". I need the regex to match a count of %X contained in log message against count of arguments. If does not match then display as result. Arguments are separated with , may or may not have additional [space] after, log end is ;

Example of invalid log:

```
g_Log.Add(0, __FILE__, __FUNCTION__, "Argument1: %s Argument2: %d Argument3: %s", Argument1, Argument2);
```

In this example argument 3 is missing. In other meaning count of %X =! count of arguments

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: The project itself is in Visual C++, however, a regular expression regex would be enough, just to search for criteria unmatched scenarios

Comment: and how invalid log would looks like?

Comment: I updated first topic with invalid log example

Comment: In C++, there are no balanced constructs as in .NET, or recursion as in PCRE. Thus, do not use regex, create a custom method for that check.

Comment: I was about to use regex from external software that would search all .cpp files, therefore I requested a help in regular expression regex to match my need :)